If $a+b+c=3$, how to show $\frac{1}{2+a^2+b^2}+\frac{1}{2+a^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{2+b^2+c^2}\leq\frac{3}{4}$?
This is a random feed popped up in my social media app. I assume that it is probably an exercise for high-schoool math contests.
I found a proof but it is very tedious and relies mostly on checking derivatives:

Rewrite the LHS by defining $A=\frac{a+b}2$ and $B=\frac{a-b}2$: $$
\frac{1}{2(1+A^2+B^2)}+\frac{1}{\mu_A+(B+A)^2}+\frac{1}{\mu_A+(B-A)^2}$$ where $\mu_A=2+(3-2A)^2$.
For any given $A$, I found that the above is maximized when $B=0$ by checking the derivative with respect to $B$. (The first terms is clearly maximized at $B=0$. So I only need to check the derivative of the last two terms that are in similar form. The derivative turns out to be $-B$ multiplied by a positive rational function of $A$ and $B$. )
Fixing $B=0$, the objective is reduced to $$
\frac{1}{2(1+A^2)}+\frac{2}{5A^2-12A+11}=\frac12\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}+\frac{2}{5x^2-2x+4}
$$where $x=A-1$.
This is maximized at $x=0$, again by checking the derivatives, with maximum being $\frac34$. (After lengthing algebra, the derivative turns out to be $-x$ multiplied by a positive rational function of $x$.)

My question is how to prove the inequality using other simpler/well-known inequalities and/or relying on the symmetry of the problem, without the need to explicitly examine the derivatives.

Iran TST 2009: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h275815

@ngu Thank you so much. That's very helpful.

@nguyenhuyenag's link provided several proofs and the following is one of them.
$$\begin{align*}
 & \sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{2+a^{2}+b^{2}}\leq\frac{3}{4}\\
\iff & \sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(\frac{1}{2+a^{2}+b^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq\frac{3}{4}-\frac{3}{2}=-\frac{3}{4}\\
\iff & \sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{-\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)}{2\left(2+a^{2}+b^{2}\right)}\leq-\frac{3}{4}\\
\iff & \sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{a^{2}+b^{2}+2}\geq\frac{3}{2}.
\end{align*}$$
But
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{a^{2}+b^{2}+2} & \geq\frac{\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\right)^{2}}{6+\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)} \tag{Cauchy-Schwarz ineq.}\\
 & =\frac{\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}\sqrt{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)}}{6+\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)}\\
 & =\frac{2\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}\sqrt{a^{4}+a^{2}\left(b^{2}+c^{2}\right)+b^{2}c^{2}}}{2\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+3\right)}\\
 & \geq\frac{2\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}\sqrt{a^{4}+2a^{2}\left|bc\right|+\left|bc\right|^{2}}}{2\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+3\right)}  \tag{Cauchy-Schwarz ineq.}\\
 & =\frac{2\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(a^{2}+\left|bc\right|\right)}{2\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+3\right)}\\
 & \geq\frac{2\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(a^{2}+bc\right)}{2\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+3\right)}\\
 & =\frac{3\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}bc}{2\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+3\right)}\\
 & =\frac{3\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\right)^{2}}{2\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+3\right)}\\
 & =\frac{3\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+9}{2\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^{2}+3\right)}=\frac{3}{2}.
\end{align*}$$
